# admin invalid username and password error

Tags: php, mysql

code for sql connection:

```
<?php 
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS' ,'');
define('DB_NAME', 'shopping');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

code for login:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include("include/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
    $num=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
    if($num>0)
    {
        $extra="change-password.php";//
        $_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id']=$num['id'];
        $host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri=rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\');
        header("location:http://$host$uri/$extra");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['errmsg']="Invalid username or password";
        $extra="index.php";
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\');
        header("location:http://$host$uri/$extra");
        exit();
    }
 }
 ?>
```

It gives invalid username and password error all time even username and password are correct. Connection with mysql server done and work properly but issue with login as admin in admin penal.

Comment: **don't use md5** for hashing passwords! it's insecure for **decades** - use `password_hash` and `password_verify`. and use parameterised statements, your code is wide open to **SQL injection attacks**. this code basically screams "hey, hackers, here's my password, and everybody elses, too"

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array, not a number. Use `count($num) > 0` instead